# Matlab vector with names not numbers

Tags: matlab, vector, names

Ho can I make a vector like this M = ['Peter', 'Maria', 'Michelle' etc.] and pick a random name from that vector?? I want to make a lottery basically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (1) a [cell array](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html) of *character vectors*:

```
M = {'Peter', 'Maria', 'Michelle'};
```

Or, using the recently introduced [string](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) data type, you can create (2) an array of *strings*:

```
M = ["Peter", "Maria", "Michelle"];
```

Then choose a random number from `1` to `numel(M)` using [`randi`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html):

```
n = randi(numel(M));
```

and use it as an index into `M`:

- With option (1), `{}`-indexing will give a character array.
- With option (2), `{}`-indexing will again give a character array. Or you can use `()`-indexing to get a string. More information about indexing with strings can be found [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html).

So:

```
winner = M{n}; % or winner = M(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cell arrays and randi function; in normal matrix all strings must be the same length, with cell arrays you can have arbitrary contents

```
M = {'Peter', 'Maria', 'Michelle'};
name = M{randi([1, numel(M)])};
```